# How to clear this error

Tags: xampp

[image]

Please check this and give me an correct answer.

```
[sudo] password for roo: 
suninfomediaSorry, try again.
[sudo] password for roo: 
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.7-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
/opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
fail.
XAMPP:  Starting diagnose... 
XAMPP:  Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong. 
XAMPP:  Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/ 
Last 10 lines of "/opt/lampp/logs/error_log":
tail: cannot open '/opt/lampp/logs/error.log' for reading: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
```

Comment: Could you please add the command you are running, not just it's output. And why does it say `[sudo] password for roo: ` shouldn't it be `... for root:` ?

Comment: "Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/ " That is not us ;-) I would advice to report it on their forums so they can create a dependency for netstat.

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get update`, then, `sudo apt-get install net-tools`.

Answer (score 2):

`netstat` is in the [net-tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/net-tools) package, which is installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools
```

You can search for packages, or package contents, on https://packages.ubuntu.com/. Alternatively you can use `apt-cache search`.